# No lifecycle when replacing Fragment if added via XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am running into an issue where replacing the initial fragment added via XML does not call any destroying lifecycle callbacks, e.g. `onDetach()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDestroyView()`, `onStop()`, ect. This is posing an issue because I want to perform an action in `onDetach()`.

Here is my setup. Following exactly what google developers docs says (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), I create a layout, activity_main.xml, with a fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sky_2"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent,contentDescription">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:name="com.example.GameFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is referenced in my MainActivity. As FYI, the included footer is just four ImageViews that represent tabs.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!Utils.checkIfNull(findViewById(R.id.frag_container))) {

            // if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (!Utils.checkIfNull(savedInstanceState)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // initialize views
        initializeViews();
    }
```

When my app launches, it launches my `GameFragment` as expected. The documents states

> When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each
>   fragment specified in the layout and calls the onCreateView() method
>   for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout. The system inserts
>   the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the 
>   element.

My GameFragment `onCreateView()` callback does get called, everything gets initialized and I am able to perform all functions. The issue comes when I change tabs. I change tabs by replacing my current fragment with the new one. Here is the function I am using.

```
public void addFragmentReplace(int containerId, @NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    // check if the fragment has been added already
    Fragment temp = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (!Utils.checkIfNull(temp) && temp.isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    // replace fragment and transition with animation
    try {
        if (!Utils.isStringEmpty(getTopFragment().getTag()) && getTopFragment().isAdded()) {
            // pop back stack
            popBackStack();
        }
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment,
                fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment,
                fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss(); // used as last resort
    }
}
```

I call the function by simply saying

```
addFragmentReplace(R.id.frag_container, new NewsFragment());
```

The behavior I am noticing is that when changing from the initial tab to any other tab, I receive no callbacks. Once I return back to that initial tab and change to any other tabs, everything works perfectly. I tried monitoring my backstackcount to further understand what could be happening. In my MainActivity's `onCreate()` method I logged the backstackcount and it comes up as 0, even though I can clearly see the GameFragment after first launching my app. When I change tabs, my backstackcount becomes 1, and remains 1 no matter how many times I change tabs because of my `addFragmentReplace()` method. I am not sure what happens when fragments are added via XML, but I think there is either an issue with doing that or my replace function is incorrect. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Fragment`s declared in your layout cannot be removed/replaced dynamically. That transaction is just sticking a `NewsFragment` on top of the static `GameFragment`.

Comment: Wow! I completely missed reading that detail, but that is exactly what I am experiencing. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Mike M so that this thread has an accepted answer. You can post your comment as your answer with a link to the docs where it is referenced and I will accept it. I resolved the issue by just doing it all programmatically. Works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, it's cool. I can find a duplicate, if you wanna keep this question. Or, if you'd like, you can post an answer. I don't deserve any rep from something you just inadvertently missed in the docs. :-) Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that if you add a fragment via XML it cannot be removed/replaced dynamically. I resolved my issue by doing everything programmatically. First, in MainActivity I add GameFragment

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (!Utils.checkIfNull(findViewById(R.id.frag_container))) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (!Utils.checkIfNull(savedInstanceState)) {
                return;
            }

            addFragment(R.id.frag_container, new GameFragment());
        }

        // initialize views
        initializeViews();
    }
```

Then I changed my XML to have a FrameLayout container, opposed to a fragment one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sky_2"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent,contentDescription">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:name="com.example.GameFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```